# PWA not showing in Android apps drawer

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Our users have been reporting that our Progressive Web App doesn't show up in their Apps drawer. I reproduced this on a Samsung Galaxy S5 and S6 running Google Chrome 65. I used the menu to "Add to Home Screen," and the icon shows up on the home screen, but doesn't show up in the "Apps" drawer or in the Application Manager Settings screen.

This indicates to me that my PWA isn't getting "WebAPK" aka "[Improved Add to Home Screen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/improved-add-to-home-screen)" treatment, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. According to that link from Google, Improved A2HS rolled out to all users in Chrome 59.

Here's my `manifest.json` file with `name`, `short_name`, `scope`, and `start_url` changed to example values.

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "short_name": "Example",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon.jpg",
      "sizes": "1024x1024",
      "type": "image/jpg"
    }
  ],
  "scope": "https://www.example.com/my-url/",
  "start_url": "https://www.example.com/my-url/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#626160",
  "theme_color": "#626160"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you're not seeing Add to Homescreen (A2HS) banner because of the icon defined as image/jpg.

> Site cannot be installed: the manifest does not contain a suitable
>   icon - PNG format of at least 144px is required, the sizes attribute
>   must be set, and the purpose attribute, if set, must include "any".

**More info:**

There are several requirements needed to get the WebAPK listed at the [Web App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners)

> Chrome automatically displays the banner when your app meets the
>   following criteria:
>
> Has a web app manifest file with:
>
> - a short_name (used on the home screen)
> - a name (used in the banner)
> - a 192x192 png icon (the icon declarations must include a mime type of    image/png)
> - a start_url that loads
> - has a service worker registered on your site
>
> Is served over HTTPS (a requirement for using service worker). Meets a
>   site engagement heuristic defined by Chrome (this is regularly being
>   changed).
>
> Starting with Chrome 68 you will need to handle "beforeinstallprompt "
>   event and call prompt() on user gesture to get the Add to Homescreen
>   (A2HS), it won't happen automatically.

[image]

[image]

**To be absolutely sure you'll get WebAPK and not a shortcut ensure the following:**

- You need GSM Core to be able to install as WebAPK
- Web Application Manifest available
- Provided icon with right size in Web Application Manifest
- Service Worker successfully registered
- Service Worker with a fetch event

Given all of the above is ok the APK service needs to be available and reachable as APK is generated on a server and installed via GMS Core. If you don't have an internet connection it will likely default to a shortcut on homescreen.

**Where can you install PWA?**

PWAs are currently installable on **Android**:

- Chrome
- Samsung
- Firefox,
- Opera,
- UC

and will soon be available on iOS, Windows 10, macOS, ChromeOS.

Ref: [Progressive Web Apps coming to all Chrome platforms](https://medium.com/@kennethrohde/progressive-web-apps-coming-to-all-chrome-platforms-80e31272e2a8)

**How to know if you got WebAPK or shortcut?**

- If PWA is in an Android app drawer - it is a WebAPK.
- If a long press on the screen icon of your PWA gives you an option to "Uninstall" - then it is a WebAPK
- If you only get an option to "Remove" - then it is a shortcut

**Testing your PWA**

Two flags that should be used when testing

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks
```

You can use `adb shell am start` which helps with starting Chrome with both enabled without going thru the UI.

Comment: To be clear, that message ("Site cannot be installed") appears when using Chrome Dev Tools -> Application -> Manifest -> Add to Home Screen. (I was just using Chrome's user-facing menu to A2HS.)

Comment: You are exactly right that my problem was having a JPG icon when I should have had a PNG icon. It's especially unfortunate that Lighthouse doesn't flag this in its PWA audits. I've filed a bug on this. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/4876

Comment: I am using SuperPWA plugin for the wordpress blog. For some of the mobile phones such as Huawei P9 and Vivo V4 models the PWA is installed as a ShortCut. and some modes such as Huawei Rio L01 it is installed as a WebApk; and for XioMi phones chrome browser there isn't any prompt to install PWA. My goal is to install PWA as a WebAPK on all types of Android devices. How can I fix this?

Comment: If the user has not logged into their google account, the PWA would not install. It will be saved as a bookmark. So make sure that the user has logged in.

Comment: @SahilPatel have you seen any workarounds for the login issue? I would like to install a PWA without users having to login

Answer (score 0):

**Even all is set as per Matija response for a WebAPK to be installed you might still get a shortcut.**

This happened today 23 Nov 2020.
The only difference was that we used **3G data** *instead of **WiFi***.

The same process via WiFi on the same device resulted in a WebAPK install.
It seems that Google may be deciding on **WebAPK vs Shortcut** based on **connection speed available** to the device. Keep this in mind.

It will be great if more people can confirm this observation for:
 **Android version 7.0** via **Chrome 86.0.4240.198** without any user being signed with Chrome